Does the paper “A Heuristic Proof of P ≠ NP” actually prove that P ≠ NP?
I saw a paper on eprint that says 'A Heuristic Proof of P ≠ NP', does this mean that P ≠ NP has been proven? The URL of the paper is: https://eprint.iacr.org/2024/2035.

The paper is by Ping Wang and has been read by Antoine Joux. But as it is in pre-print and since there haven't been any references to it. The paper does seem to show a problem where $P \neq NP$, and if I'm not mistaken that's enough to proof that $P \neq NP$ as we're talking about sets of problems. But this seems to be fresh paper and I guess a full review is required to say anything definitive.

"it shows that the square-root complexity is necessary to solve the Add/XNOR problem" In many false proof usually this's the place where author makes false assumption that the algorithm "must behave in a certain way" as mentioned by Michael Sipser from MIT

Using "Heuristic" and "Proof" together seems like a contradiction in itself.

As also indicated in the comments, the attempted proof seems to assume a certain type of algorithm to solve the Add/XNOR problem, which would make the proof invalid.
Peter Shor, in theoretical computer science stack exchange answered the same question as below:
The paper contains the statement:

"The high-degree terms involving products of $x_i$
cannot be simplified or linearized without assigning values to $x_i$. Due to the multiplicative and recursive nature of the equations, isolating $x_i$ or expressing them in terms of other variables is not feasible,"

Shor then concludes:

This seems to indicate that he is (probably without realizing it) assuming a very particular type of algorithm for solving the problem. Thus, this paper does not contain a proof that $P ≠
 NP$, and seems very unlikely to lead to one.


Thanks. I didn't find that question before I asked.
